# How to check if the latest Cloud Run revision is ready to serve

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cdn, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-run

I've been using Cloud Run for a while and the entire user experience is simply amazing!

Currently I'm using Cloud Build to deploy the container image, push the image to GCR, then create a new Cloud Run revision.
Now I want to call a script to purge caches from CDN after the latest revision is successfully deployed to Cloud Run, however `$ gcloud run deploy` command can't tell you if the traffic is started to pointing to the latest revision.

Is there any command or the event that I can subscribe to to make sure no traffic is pointing to the old revision, so that I can safely purge all caches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Dustin’s answer is correct, however "status" messages are an indirect result of `Route` configuration, as those things are updated separately (and you might see a few seconds of delay between them). The status message will still be able to tell you the Revision has been taken out of rotation if you don't mind this.

To answer this specific question (emphasis mine) using API objects directly:

> Is there any command or the event that I can subscribe to to **make sure no traffic is pointing to the old revision**?

You need to look at `Route` objects on the API. This is a Knative API (it's available on Cloud Run) but it doesn't have a `gcloud` command: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.routes

For example, assume you did 50%-50% traffic split on your Cloud Run service. When you do this, you’ll find your `Service` object (which you can see on Cloud Console → Cloud Run → YAML tab) has the following `spec.traffic` field:

```
spec:
  traffic:
  - revisionName: hello-00002-mob
    percent: 50
  - revisionName: hello-00001-vat
    percent: 50
```

This is "desired configuration" but it actually might not reflect the status definitively. Changing this field will go and update `Route` object –which decides how the traffic is splitted.

To see the `Route` object under the covers (sadly I'll have to use curl here because no `gcloud` command for this:)

```
TOKEN="$(gcloud auth print-access-token)"

curl -vH "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
    https://us-central1-run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/GCP_PROJECT/routes/SERVICE_NAME
```

This command will show you the output:

```
  "spec": {
    "traffic": [
      {
        "revisionName": "hello-00002-mob",
        "percent": 50
      },
      {
        "revisionName": "hello-00001-vat",
        "percent": 50
      }
    ]
  },
```

(which you might notice is identical with Service’s `spec.traffic` –because it's copied from there) that can tell you definitively which revisions are currently serving traffic for that particular Service.

Comment: Thanks Ahmet!

> This is "desired configuration" but it actually might not reflect the status definitively

Yes that is the exact problem I worried about when I run `$ gcloud run services describe` command. (just as I do for my k8s services)

Inspecting `Route` object might be the perfect solution for this :)

Comment:  don’t forget to mark the question as complete if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `gcloud run revisions list` to get a list of all revisions:

```
$ gcloud run revisions list --service helloworld

   REVISION          ACTIVE  SERVICE     DEPLOYED                 DEPLOYED BY
✔  helloworld-00009  yes     helloworld  2019-08-17 02:09:01 UTC  email@email.com
✔  helloworld-00008          helloworld  2019-08-17 01:59:38 UTC  email@email.com
✔  helloworld-00007          helloworld  2019-08-13 22:58:18 UTC  email@email.com
✔  helloworld-00006          helloworld  2019-08-13 22:51:18 UTC  email@email.com
✔  helloworld-00005          helloworld  2019-08-13 22:46:14 UTC  email@email.com
✔  helloworld-00004          helloworld  2019-08-13 22:41:44 UTC  email@email.com
✔  helloworld-00003          helloworld  2019-08-13 22:39:16 UTC  email@email.com
✔  helloworld-00002          helloworld  2019-08-13 22:36:06 UTC  email@email.com
✔  helloworld-00001          helloworld  2019-08-13 22:30:03 UTC  email@email.com
```

You can also use `gcloud run revisions describe` to get details about a specific revision, which will contain a `status` field. For example, an active revision:

```
$ gcloud run revisions describe helloworld-00009
...
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: '2019-08-17T02:09:07.871Z'
    status: 'True'
    type: Ready
  - lastTransitionTime: '2019-08-17T02:09:14.027Z'
    status: 'True'
    type: Active
  - lastTransitionTime: '2019-08-17T02:09:07.871Z'
    status: 'True'
    type: ContainerHealthy
  - lastTransitionTime: '2019-08-17T02:09:05.483Z'
    status: 'True'
    type: ResourcesAvailable
```

And an inactive revision:

```
$ gcloud run revisions describe helloworld-00008
...
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: '2019-08-17T01:59:45.713Z'
    status: 'True'
    type: Ready
  - lastTransitionTime: '2019-08-17T02:39:46.975Z'
    message: Revision retired.
    reason: Retired
    status: 'False'
    type: Active
  - lastTransitionTime: '2019-08-17T01:59:45.713Z'
    status: 'True'
    type: ContainerHealthy
  - lastTransitionTime: '2019-08-17T01:59:43.142Z'
    status: 'True'
    type: ResourcesAvailable
```

You'll specifically want to check the `type: Active` condition.

This is all available via the Cloud Run REST API as well: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.revisions

Answer (score 1):

By default, the traffic is routed to the latest revision. You can see this into the logs.

```
Deploying container to Cloud Run service [SERVICE_NAME] in project [YOUR_PROJECT] region [YOUR_REGION]
✓ Deploying... Done.                                                           
  ✓ Creating Revision...
  ✓ Routing traffic...
Done.
Service [SERVICE_NAME] revision [SERVICE_NAME-00012-yic] has been deployed and is serving 100 percent of traffic at https://SERVICE_NAME-vqg64v3fcq-uc.a.run.app
```

If you want to be sure, you can explicitly call the update traffic command

```
gcloud run services update-traffic --platform=managed --region=YOUR_REGION --to-latest YOUR_SERVICE
```