# How to list non-active revisions of Cloud Run?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-run

This is somewhat similar to [How to check if the latest Cloud Run revision is ready to serve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61657875/how-to-check-if-the-latest-cloud-run-revision-is-ready-to-serve)

I would like to list non-active revisions of my Cloud Run service so that I can delete them. I can list them using:

```
gcloud run revisions list --region europe-west1 --service service-name
```

The listing looks like:

```
   REVISION                ACTIVE  SERVICE       DEPLOYED                 DEPLOYED BY
✔  xxxxx-server-00083-ban  yes     xxxxx-server  2022-12-22 18:13:50 UTC  xxxxx-server@***.iam.gserviceaccount.com
✔  xxxxx-server-00082-few          xxxxx-server  2022-12-22 18:09:27 UTC  xxxxx-server@***.iam.gserviceaccount.com
✔  xxxxx-server-00081-zex          xxxxx-server  2022-12-22 18:03:00 UTC  xxxxx-server@***.iam.gserviceaccount.com
✔  xxxxx-server-00080-bad          xxxxx-server  2022-12-22 18:02:02 UTC  xxxxx-server@***.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Now I would like to filter only those which do not have `ACTIVE:yes`. I have tried adding `--filter='-active:*'`, but it does not seem to have any effect and I am given an warning:

```
WARNING: The following filter keys were not present in any resource : active
```

When I try listing the information with `--format=JSON` or `--format=YAML`, I am overwhelmed with information, which includes listing all past status transitions like:

```
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: '2022-12-22T18:14:04.208603Z'
    status: 'True'
    type: Ready
  - lastTransitionTime: '2022-12-22T18:24:23.335439Z'
    reason: Reserve
    severity: Info
    status: Unknown
    type: Active
```

I have no idea if / how I can filter based on this.

How can I list only non-active Cloud Run revisions of my service?

Comment: Why do you want to delete inactive revision? There is no cost!

Comment: Just to keep things tidy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this command to do that :)

```bash
# Get non running revisions

gcloud run revisions list \
   --filter="status.conditions.type:Active AND status.conditions.status:'False'" \
   --format='value(metadata.name)'
```

And here u can delete them all at once :)

```
REVS=`gcloud run revisions list --filter="status.conditions.type:Active AND status.conditions.status:'False'" --format='value(metadata.name)'`

for rev in `echo $REVS`; do
    echo $rev
    gcloud run revisions delete $rev --quiet &
done
```

Comment: This appeared to be returning any revisions that matched the requested attributes in ANY of the conditions. In order to specify that `Active` and `status: False` fell within the same condition, I had to add `--flatten=status.conditions`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what after some experimentation works for me eventually, including iterating the list and deleting all inactive revisions:

```
# List last created revision (it should be the active one)
ACTIVE=$(gcloud run services describe xxxxx-server --format="value(status.latestCreatedRevisionName)" --region=europe-west1)
if [ "$ACTIVE" != "" ]; then
  gcloud run revisions list --region europe-west1 --service xxxxx-server --filter="metadata.name!=$ACTIVE" --format="get(metadata.name)" >nonactive
  echo "Delete all but $ACTIVE"
  while read p; do gcloud run revisions delete --region europe-west1 $p --quiet; done < nonactive
fi
```

Comment: Beware this approach, the latest created revision may not be the one active !!!!